# How to get HTML code from elements which don't appear in the source code with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm working in an App that uses Web scraping, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get some data from a web page. I can see the info that I'm looking for when i use "inspect element" in Firefox:

[image]

The thing is that it doesn't appear in the HTML code of the page, which i actually can get using selenium, the data i look for is obviously database driven and I'm stuck right there, Is there a way to scrap this out with selenium?

This is the url btw: http://2ez.gg/#gg?name=Doombag&server=lan

Comment: Please make your question [mcve]. Also check [ask] to make your post answerable.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be trying to scrape http://lan.op.gg/summoner/userName=Doombag instead, http://2ez.gg/#gg?name=Doombag&server=lan contains an iframe which is why you can't find 55% in the document body.

Comment: Oh, TY so much, how do i notice when this happens to me again?

Comment: I didn't see the iframe to begin with either, I only noticed the iframe when I was inspecting the page in the Chrome DevTools.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the data you want to retrieve is contained inside the iframe, which has caused the selenium cannot visit the data directly.
Try the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
URL='http://2ez.gg/#gg?name=Doombag&server=lan'

driver.get(URL)
driver.switch_to.frame('iframe-content')
elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.WinRatioGraph div.Text')
print(elem.text)
```

Output: 55%